# Check CurrentDate PHP

Tags: php

I am doing a check to check if currentDate is set and if not use the date of today but it crashes my website.

```
$currentDate = if(empty($currentDate)) ? strtotime(strftime('%d-%m-%Y', time())) : $currentDate;
```

What is wrong with that?

Comment: remove if and also use isset function

Comment: That's not valid syntax for the ternary operator

Comment: `if(empty($currentDate))` should just be `empty($currentDate)` -  look up ternary operator in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: Thank you very much, really appreciate it.